# Get line number with xml validation in C#

Tags: c#, xml, validation

I have an xml file that i need to validate. I have added a tag called "Ln" for line number. I'm trying to return this line number when there is a validation error as part of the error list. Here is my xml:

```
<employees>
    <employee>
        <firstName>John</firstName> <lastName>Doe</lastName><Ln>0</Ln>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <firstName>Anna</firstName> <lastName>Smith</lastName><Ln>1</Ln>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <firstName>Peter</firstName> <lastName>Jones</lastName><Ln>2</Ln>
    </employee>

</employees>
```

I use the following code to validate it:

```
System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaSet schemas = new System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaSet();
    schemas.Add("", @"Path to xsd");
    Console.WriteLine("Attempting to validate");
    XDocument UsrDoc = XDocument.Load(@"My xml file");
    bool errors = false;
    UsrDoc.Validate(schemas, (o, e) =>
                         {
                             Console.WriteLine("{0}", e.Message);
                             errors = true;
                         });
    Console.WriteLine("UsrDoc {0}", errors ? "did not validate" : "validated");
    Console.WriteLine();
```

I would like to return the error list as a list of strings and most importantly include the line number. I have failed so far to figure out how.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

B

Answer (score 4):

I used a `XmlReader` to validate

```
using (var stream = new FileStream("My xml file", FileMode.Open))
{
    var isErrorOccurred = false;

    XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
    settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
    settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessInlineSchema;
    settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation;
    settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;
    settings.Schemas.Add("", "my schema");
    settings.ValidationEventHandler += (sender, args) =>
    {
        isErrorOccurred = true;
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", args.Exception.LineNumber);;
    };

    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream, settings);

    // Parse the file. 
    while (reader.Read())
    {}
    if (isErrorOccurred)
        // do something
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The XmlSchemaException from the ValidationEventArgs has the LineNumber.
see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemaexception(v=vs.110).aspx

in your code:

```
    UsrDoc.Validate(schemas, (o, e) =>
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Line {0}: {1}", e.Exception.LineNumber, e.Message);
      errors = true;
    });
```

There are also other useful informations, such as LinePosition and so on.

EDIT: I just read that you want a list of strings: In this case you have to build this list in the event handler or pass the information you need to another method. However, i am not sure if the validation process continues after the first error? Maybe you have to set specific settings to keep it running.

Comment: Line number is always 0. hummm.

Comment: @BertrandPaul: Maybe this helps solving your issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914369/validating-xml-on-xsd-with-the-error-line-numbers