# Validate XML with line numbers in errors

Tags: powershell, xsd-validation

I am trying to get XML validation errors with line numbers, and the fact that there is a `LineNumberOffset` property of `[xml.xmlReaderSettings]` suggests this is possible. But I can't seem to find how to either enable line numbers, or access line numbers in the resultant error. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914369/validating-xml-on-xsd-with-the-error-line-numbers) talks about doing it in C# with `LoadOptions.SetLineInfo;` but that's not a valid property when I try `$xmlReaderSettings.SetLineInfo = $true`.

```
function readXMLFile ([string]$path) {
    $readXMLFile = [psCustomObject]@{    
        xml    = [xml.xmlDocument]::New()
        error = $null
    }
        
    $fileStream = $null
    $xmlreader = $null
    $importFile = [xml.xmlDocument]::New()
    $xmlReaderSettings = [xml.xmlReaderSettings]::New()
    #$xmlReaderSettings.ignoreComments = $true
    $xmlReaderSettings.closeInput = $true
    $xmlReaderSettings.prohibitDtd = $false
    $xmlReaderSettings.ValidationType = [System.Xml.ValidationType]::Schema
    $xmlReaderSettings.ValidationFlags = [System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidationFlags]::ProcessInlineSchema -bor
                                         [System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidationFlags]::ProcessSchemaLocation -bor 
                                         [System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidationFlags]::ReportValidationWarnings
    $xmlReaderSettings.Schemas.Add($Null, $SchemaFile)


    try {
        $fileStream = [io.fileStream]::New($path, [System.IO.FileMode]::Open, [System.IO.FileAccess]::Read, [System.IO.FileShare]::ReadWrite)
        $xmlreader = [xml.xmlreader]::Create($fileStream, $xmlReaderSettings)
        $importFile.Load($xmlreader)
    } catch {
        $exceptionName = $_.exception.GetType().name
        $exceptionMessage = $_.exception.message
        switch ($exceptionName) {
            MethodInvocationException {
                if ($exceptionMessage -match ': "(?<string>.*)"$') {
                    $readXMLFile.error = "Error loading XML; $($matches['string'])"
                } else {
                    $readXMLFile.error = "Error loading XML; $exceptionMessage"
                }
            }
            Default {
                $readXMLFile.error = "Error loading XML; $($exceptionName) - $exceptionMessage" # Or just the message?
            }
        }
    } finally {
        if ($xmlreader) {
            $xmlreader.Dispose()
        }
        if ($readXMLFile.error) {
            $readXMLFile.xml = $null
        } else {
            $readXMLFile.xml = $importFile
        }
    }
        
    return $readXMLFile
}
```

EDIT: The schema I have been working on is

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name = 'Definitions'>
        <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name = 'Sets' type = 'Sets' minOccurs = '0'  maxOccurs = '1' />
            <xs:element name = 'Packages' type = 'Packages' minOccurs = '0'  maxOccurs = '1' />
         </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    
    <xs:complexType name = 'Sets'>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name = "Set" type = 'Set' minOccurs = '0' maxOccurs='unbounded' />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    
    <xs:complexType name = 'Set'>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name = 'Set' type='xs:string' minOccurs = '0' maxOccurs='unbounded' />
            <xs:element name = 'Package' type='xs:string' minOccurs = '0' maxOccurs='unbounded' />
            <xs:element name = 'Rollout' type='xs:string' minOccurs = '0' maxOccurs='unbounded' />
            <xs:element name = 'Remove' type='xs:string' minOccurs = '0' maxOccurs='unbounded' />
        </xs:sequence>
        <!--<xs:attribute name = 'id' type = 'xs:string'/>-->
    </xs:complexType>
    
    <xs:complexType name = 'Packages'>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name = 'Package' type = 'Package' minOccurs = '0' maxOccurs='unbounded' />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name = 'id' type = 'xs:string'/>
    </xs:complexType>
    
    <xs:complexType name = 'Package'>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name = 'Package' type='xs:string' minOccurs = '0' maxOccurs='unbounded' />
            <xs:element name = 'Task' type='Task' minOccurs = '0' maxOccurs='unbounded' />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    
    
    
    <xs:complexType name = 'Task'>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name = 'PreProcess' type='TaskPrePostProcess' minOccurs = '0' maxOccurs='1' />
            <xs:element name = 'Process' type='TaskProcess' minOccurs = '1' maxOccurs='1' />
            <xs:element name = 'PostProcess' type='TaskPrePostProcess' minOccurs = '0' maxOccurs='1' />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name = 'TaskPrePostProcess'>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name = 'Task' type='Task' minOccurs = '0' maxOccurs='unbounded' />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name = 'TaskProcess'>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

And some simple sample data would be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Definitions>
    <Sets>
        <Set id="Arch">
            <Package>DTV_2017</Package>
        </Set>
        <Set id="Px_Arch">
            <Package>RVT_2017</Package>
            <Package>RVT_2018</Package>
        </Set>
    </Sets> 

    <Packages>
    </Packages>
</Definitions>
```

EDIT: Interestingly, when I remove the validation and just catch malformed XML errors, I DO get line numbers. It's only validating with the XSD file that produces errors that aren't particularly helpful.

Comment: Do you have a schema + an invalid sample document to test against?

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen Updated with XML & XSD examples. At least I made sure I wasn't testing on a Windows 7/PS 2.0 machine, as I have a few times. It's Windows 10/PS5.1 this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're fighting with some of PowerShell's black magic around the way it sometimes wraps objects with its own types `:-(`.

If you look at the `System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException` you caught, you'll see it's got an `InnerException` property which contains the `System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidationException` instance that the `XmlReader` actually threw, and **that** has got the `LineNumber` and `LinePosition` properties that you want.

However, a cleaner way is to only catch `XmlSchemaValidationException` exceptions in the first place and let everything else throw. That way, PowerShell gives you the original exception rather than its wrapper:

```bsh
catch [System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidationException]
{
    $ex = $_.Exception;
    $type = $ex.GetType().FullName;
    $lineNumber = $ex.LineNumber;
    $linePosition = $ex.LinePosition;
    $message = $ex.Message;
    write-host "type = $type";
    write-host "line = $lineNumber";
    write-host "position = $linePosition";
    write-host "message = $message";
    ...
}
```

which outputs:

```
type = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidationException
line = 4
position = 14
message = The 'id' attribute is not declared.
```

As an aside, you might want also to capture the return value from `$xmlReaderSettings.Schemas.Add($Null, $SchemaFile)` otherwise it'll be written to the output stream from your function and will give some odd results...

```
$null = $xmlReaderSettings.Schemas.Add($Null, $SchemaFile)
```